# Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier in autogenerated ModuleName-Swift.h file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a project with swift and ObjC sources and have a strange message in autogenerated header file:

[image]

The code, that marked with error:

```
//interface in ModuleName-Swift.h  file
@interface PointsList : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithPoints:(NSArray<NSValue *> * /*this marked with warning*/_Nonnull)points OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER; //Warning:Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithValues:(NSArray<NSValue *> * /*this marked with warning*/_Nonnull)pointValues //Warning:Pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified)
@end



//source PointsList.swift
   @objc public class PointsList : NSObject {

    var points = Array<CGPoint>()
    @objc public override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    @objc public init(withPoints points: Array<CGPoint>) {
        self.points.append(contentsOf: points)
        super.init()
    }
    @objc public init(withValues pointValues: Array<NSValue>) {
        super.init()
        pointValues.forEach { (pointValue) in
                self.points.append(pointValue.cgPointValue)
        }
    }
}
```

This file is generated by Xcode from swift's classes. I see _Nunnull modifier but XCode complains that I should add that modifier
. Maybe I've forgot some setting in project configuration.
How I can fix this strange behaviour?

*UPD*
I have same issue with Swift 5  and Xcode 10.2.
It is strange  because other files in my project are processed in a correct way.
Problem only with `_Nonnull` and `_Nullable` modifiers. Xcode ignore them, if I press to a button `Fix` in the warning message, Xcode adds second modifier to the pointer and the warning does not move away.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted relevant code as text into your question.

Comment: I've updated my question. I've add example of generated interface  and source class that produce that warning.

Comment: Seems like an compiler issue. Did you try do to a clean build?

Comment: Yeah. Without changes. I had same issue in Xcode 9 and have in Xcode 10 :(

Comment: There seems to be something missing, the Swift code does not compile (self.points is undefined)

Comment: I've updated code. But I think what the problem does not lie in code. Because I have same problem with all .swift classes. All of them have same warnings in the ModuleName-Swift.h. 
I think problem lies somewhere in project's settings.

Comment: What is `OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` after the `init`? Shouldn't it be `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: This is synonym of NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER: 
# if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))
# else
#  define OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
# endif

Comment: An `init` may fail, e.g. if there is too less memory to instantiate the object. Thus a type specifier `(nonnull instancetype)` for an `init` seems strange to me. I think the compiler is right, the type should be `nullable`. But since this is autogenerated coded, I guess this is a compiler error.

Comment: This file is generated as interface for a swift class. A Nullable init in Swift is a special situation, that should be described in the Swift’s interface. Also, I’ve marked position, where the compiler complains. In some reason the compiler does not see _Nullble and _Nonnullable keywords, but he sees nullable and nonnullable. I think some config exists in a project’s settings to configure the list of keywords (it is very old and big project). I do not have same problem with other new projects.

Comment: what class is the `initWithCoder` method inside of? The code you paste later (and when run on my machine) doesn't show or generate an `initWithCoder`. also what is the full contents of the warning?

Comment: I have this problem only in one project :(. Same code in other project works ok. If I try to use _Nonnull modifier, the Xcode will complain what I should add nullability modifier for that place.   initWithCoder it is just one of many examples, in what class this method exists doesn't matter (In this case it is subclass of UIView).

Answer (score 0):

In pure ObjC you shouldn't really need to use `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull`. These are lower lever calls than `nullable` and `nonull` that should only be necessary when doing C++ things (like typedefs and blocks).

Really you shouldn't ever have to use `nonnull` either. The only identifier I generally use is `nullable`. The reason for this is you should be using `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN/NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END` wrappers in your ObjC code, not only for readability, but for more verbose compiler warnings/errors and better Swift interoperability.

Recommend writing your ObjC classes similar to this:

```
// SomeClass.h

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
-(instancetype)initWithRequiredSomething:(NSString *)requiredString optionalSomething:(nullable NSString *)optionalString;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The return value and `requiredString` are both implicitly `nonnull` and `optionalString` is `nullable`

Try going through your project and removing all instances of `_Nullable`, `_Nonnull` and `nonnull`, you may find it to be quite satisfying (and hopefully fix the problem!).

Comment: Problem is not with ObjC classes, problem with generated interfaces for swift classes. In ObjC classes, I use  NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN/END and nullable modifiers. If you pay some attention for comments in code that I've added,  you will see, that warnings present in the generated interfaces. Also I do not have same problem in other projects. This is very old project (since Xcode 4).

Comment: your comment above says "If I try to use _Nonnull modifier, the Xcode will complain" which makes it sound like you are hand adding a `_Nonnull`. Is that not the case?

Comment: I think it is global problem in the project, not only in the generated file. I tried to find nullability marker for C functions and could not find it (xCode complained to all markers, but shouldn't complains to _Nonnull, _Nullable). Also I can't use 'nullable' in block's arguments, because the blocks are a part of C, not Objective-C. Main problem only with the generated file, after compilation I see >>300 warnings in the file, and it is not very good, because I can loose the important warnings in other files.

Comment: I’ve seen similar issues when an NS_ASSUME_NONULL_BEGIN is missing its matching _END. Confirm via a search that you have the same number of each identifier

Comment: I've checked it, I have 245 BEGINs and 245 ENDs. Also I've checked what  end follow after begin, all correct. :( .

Comment: It looks like, Xcode does not see  _Nonnull/_Nullable macros: if I add one of that macroses to file without nullability modifier (and without BEGIN/END) for one pointer, Xcode does not complain for other pointers. But if I add nullable/nonnullable modifier  to one pointer, Xcode will complain to other pointers.